# pretty-fullcalendar package in meteor and event background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

pulling out what little hair I have left here trying to follow the docs on the js fullcalendar control to get the background of individual events to change.

I've followed several other threads on here such as [Adding nice colors to events in FullCalendar (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760837/adding-nice-colors-to-events-in-fullcalendar-jquery) and [fullcalendar backgroundColor property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292847/fullcalendar-backgroundcolor-property) which all suggest I set the property backgroundColor of the event, or set up a class and attach it to the event, all of which are ignored.

The only thing I can manage to get to change is if I set the color property of the event, which changes the border color to suite (which according to the docs, should set the color of the entire event).

I'm setting these properties as I push them into an array of events to pass to the calendar as follows

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
        var events = [];
        reqEvents = Requests.find();
        reqEvents.forEach(function(evt){
          event = {id:evt._id,title:evt.title,start:evt.start,end:evt.end,color:evt.color};
          event.className = 'todo';
          events.push(event);
        })
        callback(events);
        console.log(events);
      },
```

This is in the template render function.

I've tried event.backgroundColor = 'green' in place of the className, I've tried doing this inline, I've tried just about ever color named event I can find in the docs, but nothing changes the background or text colors.

Ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not your problem, rather, it is a bug with how fullcalendar is packaged  for meteor.

As you can see at https://github.com/priyadarshy/meteor-fullcalendar/tree/master/css that both screen and print stylesheets are included and the way meteor packages css is bundling them all together.

The print stylesheet unfortunately overrides all backgrounds.

In fact on this file https://github.com/priyadarshy/meteor-fullcalendar/blob/master/css/fullcalendar.print.css it states

> Include this stylesheet on your page to get a more printer-friendly
>   calendar. When including this stylesheet, use the media='print'
>   attribute of the  tag. Make sure to include this stylesheet IN
>   ADDITION to the regular fullcalendar.css.

What you can do is to clone this repo, and then either delete the print css or surround the print css with

```
@media print {

  /* print css goes here */

}
```

Comment: I've also placed a pull request for a fix at https://github.com/priyadarshy/meteor-fullcalendar/pull/1